# Delete record in new dac with application mobile

Tags: acumatica

I add the "CRM" tab on the screen :

[image]

I can add the new record with

[image]
[image]

```
  add container "PIPELINE" {
 fieldsToShow = 4
    displayName = "Pipeline"
    add field "Date"         
    add field "Origine"
    add field "Raison"
    add containerAction "Insert" {
    icon = "system://Plus"
    behavior = Create
    redirect = True
 }
```

But it's not ok for delete an record, no options appear !

```
  add containerAction "Delete" {
 icon = "system://Trash"
 behavior = Delete
 after = Close
 }
```

The ERP form is :

[image]

In the WSDL, I have this information :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the existing Mobile Site Map entry for SO Order Entry, you can see an example of where the Delete action is included in the Details container.

I think you want to use recordAction:

```
add recordAction "Delete" {
  icon = "system://Trash"
  behavior = Delete
}
```

SO301000 for reference:

```
add screen SO301000 {
  add container "OrderSummary" {
    formActionsToExpand = 1
    add layout "OrderHeader" {
      displayName = "OrderHeader"
      layout = "HeaderSimple"
      add layout "OrderHeaderNbrRow" {
        displayName = "OrderHeaderNbrRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "OrderNbr"
        add field "OrderTotal"
      }
      add layout "OrderHeaderTaxTotalRow" {
        displayName = "OrderHeaderTaxTotalRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "Status"
        add field "DiscountTotal"
      }
      add layout "OrderHeaderTotalRow" {
        displayName = "OrderHeaderTotalRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "OrderedQty"
        add field "TaxTotal"
      }
    }
    add layout "OrderTypeRow" {
      displayName = "OrderTypeRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "OrderType" {
        selector {
      add field "OrderType"
          add field "Description"
        }
      }
      add field "Currency"
    }
    add field "ControlTotal"
    add layout "OrderDateRow" {
      displayName = "OrderDateRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "Date"
      add field "RequestedOn"
    }
    add field "Customer" {
      selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
      pickerType = Searchable
    }
    add field "Location" {
      selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
      pickerType = Detached
    }
    add field "Contact" {
        pickerType = Searchable
        selector {
            fieldsToShow = 3
            add field "Contact"
            add field "JobTitle"
            add field "Email"
            add field "ContactID" {
                forceIsVisible = False
            }
        }
    }
    add field "DestinationWarehouse"
    add field "Description"
    add field "NoteText" {
      displayName = "Notes"
      textType = PlainMultiLine
    }
    add group "ShipInfoGroup" {
      displayName = "Shipping"
      collapsable = True
      collapsed = True
      add layout "ShipViaRow" {
        displayName = "ShipViaRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "ShippingDeliverySettings#ShipVia"
        add field "ShippingDeliverySettings#Priority"
      }
      add field "ShippingDeliverySettings#ShippingTerms"
      add layout "ShipDeliveryOpt1" {
        displayName = "ShipDeliveryOpt1"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "ShippingDeliverySettings#ResidentialDelivery"
        add field "ShippingDeliverySettings#SaturdayDelivery"
      }
      add layout "ShipDeliveryOpt2" {
        displayName = "ShipDeliveryOpt2"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "ShippingDeliverySettings#Insurance"
        add field "ShippingDeliverySettings#UseCustomerSAccount"
      }
      add field "AddressesShipToContact#OverrideContact"
      add field "AddressesShipToContact#AccountName"
      add field "AddressesShipToContact#Attention"
      add field "AddressesShipToContact#Phone1" {
        special = PhoneCall
      }
      add field "AddressesShipToContact#Email" {
        special = EmailSend
      }
      add layout "OverrideShipAddressRow" {
        displayName = "OverrideShipAddressRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "AddressesShipToAddress#OverrideAddress"
        add field "AddressesShipToAddress#Validated"
      }
      add field "AddressesShipToAddress#AddressLine1"
      add field "AddressesShipToAddress#AddressLine2"
      add field "AddressesShipToAddress#City"
      add layout "ShipStateRow" {
        displayName = "ShipStateRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "AddressesShipToAddress#State" {
          weight = 2
        }
        add field "AddressesShipToAddress#PostalCode"
      }
      add field "AddressesShipToAddress#Country"
    }
    add group "PayInfoGroup" {
      displayName = "Payment Settings"
      collapsable = True
      collapsed = True
      add field "FinancialPaymentInformation#PaymentMethod"
      add field "FinancialPaymentInformation#CardAccountNbr"
      add field "FinancialPaymentInformation#CashAccount"
      add field "FinancialPaymentInformation#PaymentRef"
    }
    add layout "DetailsTab" {
      displayName = "Details"
      layout = "DataTab"
      add containerLink "Details"
    }
    add layout "OrderSettingsTab" {
      displayName = "Settings"
      layout = "Tab"
      add group "FinInfoGroup" {
        displayName = "Financial"
        collapsable = True
        collapsed = True
        add field "FinancialFinancialInformation#Branch"
        add layout "BillTaxZoneRow" {
          displayName = "BillTaxZoneRow"
          layout = "Inline"
          add field "FinancialFinancialInformation#OverrideTaxZone"
          add field "FinancialFinancialInformation#CustomerTaxZone"
        }
        add field "FinancialFinancialInformation#EntityUsageType"
        add field "FinancialFinancialInformation#Terms"
      }
      add group "BillToInfoGroup" {
        displayName = "Bill-To Info"
        collapsable = True
        collapsed = True
        add field "AddressesBillToContact#OverrideContact"
        add field "AddressesBillToContact#AccountName"
        add field "AddressesBillToContact#Attention"
        add field "AddressesBillToContact#Phone1" {
          special = PhoneCall
        }
        add field "AddressesBillToContact#Email" {
          special = EmailSend
        }
        add layout "OverrideBillAddressRow" {
          displayName = "OverrideBillAddressRow"
          layout = "Inline"
          add field "AddressesBillToAddress#OverrideAddress"
          add field "AddressesBillToAddress#Validated"
        }
        add field "AddressesBillToAddress#AddressLine1"
        add field "AddressesBillToAddress#AddressLine2"
        add field "AddressesBillToAddress#City"
        add layout "BillStateRow" {
          displayName = "BillStateRow"
          layout = "Inline"
          add field "AddressesBillToAddress#State" {
            weight = 2
          }
          add field "AddressesBillToAddress#PostalCode"
        }
        add field "AddressesBillToAddress#Country"
      }
      add group "OtherGroup" {
        displayName = "Other"
        collapsable = True
        collapsed = True
        add layout "OrderRefNbrRow" {
          displayName = "OrderRefNbrRow"
          layout = "Inline"
          add field "CustomerOrderNbr"
          add field "ExternalReference"
        }
        add field "Project"
        add field "CommissionsDefaultSalesperson#DefaultSalesperson" {
          selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
        }
        add layout "ShipSchedRow" {
          displayName = "ShipSchedRow"
          layout = "Inline"
          add field "ShippingOrderShippingSettings#SchedShipment"
          add field "ShippingOrderShippingSettings#ShipSeparately"
        }
        add field "ShippingOrderShippingSettings#ShippingRule"
        add field "ShippingOrderShippingSettings#PreferredWarehouseID"
        add layout "ShipCancelRow" {
          displayName = "ShipCancelRow"
          layout = "Inline"
          add field "ShippingOrderShippingSettings#CancelBy"
          add field "ShippingOrderShippingSettings#Canceled"
        }
        add field "ShippingDeliverySettings#ShippingZone"
        add field "ShippingDeliverySettings#FOBPoint"
        add field "FinancialFinancialInformation#BillSeparately"
        add layout "BillInvoiceRow" {
          displayName = "BillInvoiceRow"
          layout = "Inline"
          add field "FinancialFinancialInformation#InvoiceNbr"
          add field "FinancialFinancialInformation#InvoiceDate"
        }
        add layout "BillDueRow" {
          displayName = "BillDueRow"
          layout = "Inline"
          add field "FinancialFinancialInformation#DueDate"
          add field "FinancialFinancialInformation#CashDiscountDate"
        }
        add layout "BillOrigOrderRow" {
          displayName = "BillOrigOrderRow"
          layout = "Inline"
          add field "FinancialPaymentInformationOtherInformation#OrigOrderType"
          add field "FinancialPaymentInformationOtherInformation#OrigOrderNbr"
        }
        add field "FinancialPaymentInformationOwnership#Owner"
      }
      add containerLink "Discounts"
      add containerLink "Taxes"
      add containerLink "Approvals"
      add containerLink "Commissions"
      add containerLink "Shipments"
      add containerLink "Payments"
      add containerLink "Relations"
    }
    add recordAction "Cancel" {
      behavior = Cancel
    }
    add recordAction "Save" {
      behavior = Save
    }
    add recordAction "PutOnHold" {
      behavior = Record
    }
    add recordAction "ReleaseFromHold" {
      behavior = Record
    }
    add recordAction "ReleaseFromCreditHold" {
      behavior = Record
    }
    add recordAction "Approve" {
      behavior = Record
      syncLongOperation = True
    }
    add recordAction "Reject" {
      behavior = Record
      syncLongOperation = True
    }
    add recordAction "CaptureCCPayment" {
      behavior = Record
      syncLongOperation = True
    }
    add recordAction "AuthorizeCCPayment" {
      behavior = Record
      syncLongOperation = True
    }
    add recordAction "VoidCCPayment" {
      behavior = Record
      syncLongOperation = True
    }
    add recordAction "MobileCreatePayment" {
      behavior = Void
      redirect = True
    }
    add recordAction "CancelOrder" {
      behavior = Record
      syncLongOperation = True
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
  add container "Details" {
    fieldsToShow = 3
    listActionsToExpand = 1
    formActionsToExpand = 2
    containerActionsToExpand = 1
    add field "Branch"
    add group "LineInventoryIdGroup" {
      displayName = "LineInventoryIdGroup"
      collapsed = True
      template = ExpansionPanel
      add field "InventoryID" {
        listPriority = 100
        selectorDisplayFormat = Key
        pickerType = Searchable
      }
      add field "LineDescription" {
        listPriority = 80
      }
      add layout "LineSubitemRow" {
        displayName = "LineSubitemRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "AlternateID"
        add field "Subitem"
      }
    }
    add layout "LineQuantityRow" {
      displayName = "LineQuantityRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "Quantity" {
        listPriority = 90
      }
      add field "UOM" {
        pickerType = Attached
      }
    }
    add group "LinePriceGroup" {
      displayName = "LinePriceGroup"
      collapsed = True
      template = ExpansionPanel
      add layout "LinePriceRow" {
        displayName = "LinePriceRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "UnitPrice"
        add field "DiscUnitPrice"
      }
      add layout "LineFreeItemRow" {
        displayName = "LineFreeItemRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "FreeItem"
        add field "ManualDiscount"
      }
      add layout "LineDiscountRow" {
        displayName = "LineDiscountRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "DiscountPercent"
        add field "DiscountAmount"
      }
      add field "DiscountCode" {
        pickerType = Searchable
      }
    }
    add field "ExtPrice"
    add field "Warehouse"
    add field "RequestedOn"
    add group "LineShipInfoGroup" {
      displayName = "Other"
      collapsable = True
      collapsed = True
      add field "ProjectTask" {
        pickerType = Searchable
      }
      add field "CostCode" {
        selectorDisplayFormat = Key
        selector {
          add field "CostCodeCD"
          add field "Description"
        }
      }
      add layout "ShipOnRow" {
        displayName = "ShipOnRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "ShipOn"
        add field "ShippingRule"
      }
      add layout "LineReqShipQtyRow" {
        displayName = "LineReqShipQtyRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "OpenQty"
        add field "QtyOnShipments"
      }
      add layout "LineThresholdRow" {
        displayName = "LineThresholdRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "UndershipThreshold"
        add field "OvershipThreshold"
      }
      add field "LotSerialNbr"
      add field "ExpirationDate"
      add field "ReasonCode"
      add field "MarkForPO"
      add field "POSource"
      add layout "LineTermRow" {
        displayName = "LineTermRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "TermStartDate"
        add field "TermEndDate"
      }
      add field "UnbilledAmount"
      add field "TaxCategory"
    }
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    add selectionAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
    }
    add recordAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
      after = Close
    }
    add recordAction "Insert" {
      displayName = "Add Another"
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    add recordAction "SOOrderLineSplittingExtensionShowSplits" {
      behavior = Void
      redirect = True
      redirectToContainer = "LineDetails$List"
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
  add container "Discounts" {
    fieldsToShow = 6
    listActionsToExpand = 2
    formActionsToExpand = 2
    containerActionsToExpand = 2
    add field "SkipDiscount" {
      listPriority = 50
      listDisplayFormat = CaptionValue
    }
    add layout "DiscTypeRow" {
      displayName = "DiscTypeRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "Type" {
        listPriority = 100
      }
      add field "ManualDiscount" {
        listPriority = 40
        listDisplayFormat = CaptionValue
      }
    }
    add layout "DiscCodeRow" {
      displayName = "DiscCodeRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "DiscountCode" {
        listPriority = 70
        pickerType = Searchable
        selector {
          add field "DiscountID"
          add field "Description"
        }
      }
      add field "SequenceID" {
        listPriority = 60
      }
    }
    add layout "DiscBaseRow" {
      displayName = "DiscBaseRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "DiscountableAmt"
      add field "DiscountableQty"
    }
    add layout "DiscAmtRow" {
      displayName = "DiscAmtRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "DiscountAmt" {
        listPriority = 90
      }
      add field "DiscountPercent"
    }
    add layout "DiscFreeRow" {
      displayName = "DiscFreeRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "FreeItem"
      add field "FreeItemQty"
    }
    add field "ExternalDiscountCode"
    add field "Description"
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    add selectionAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
    }
    add recordAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
      after = Close
    }
    add recordAction "Insert" {
      displayName = "Add Another"
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
  add container "Taxes" {
    fieldsToShow = 2
    listActionsToExpand = 2
    formActionsToExpand = 2
    containerActionsToExpand = 2
    add layout "TaxIdRow" {
      displayName = "TaxIdRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "TaxID" {
        listPriority = 90
      }
      add field "TaxRate"
    }
    add field "TaxType"
    add layout "TaxAmountRow" {
      displayName = "TaxAmountRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "TaxableAmount"
      add field "TaxAmount" {
        listPriority = 80
      }
    }
    add field "PendingVAT"
    add field "ReverseVAT"
    add field "IncludeInVATExemptTotal"
    add field "StatisticalVAT"
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    add selectionAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
    }
    add recordAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
      after = Close
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
  add container "Commissions" {
    fieldsToShow = 2
    listActionsToExpand = 2
    formActionsToExpand = 2
    containerActionsToExpand = 2
    add field "SalespersonID" {
      selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
    }
    add field "Commission"
    add field "CommissionAmt"
    add field "CommissionableAmount"
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    add selectionAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
    }
    add recordAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
      after = Close
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
  add container "Shipments" {
    fieldsToShow = 4
    add layout "ShipmentNbrRow" {
      displayName = "ShipmentNbrRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "ShipmentType" {
        listPriority = 80
      }
      add field "DocumentNbr" {
        listPriority = 90
      }
    }
    add field "Status" {
      listPriority = 60
    }
    add layout "ShipmentInvoiceRow" {
      displayName = "ShipmentInvoiceRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "InvoiceType"
      add field "InvoiceNbr"
    }
    add layout "ShipmentDateRow" {
      displayName = "ShipmentDateRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "ShipmentDate" {
        listPriority = 70
      }
      add field "ShippedQty"
    }
    add layout "ShipmentWeightRow" {
      displayName = "ShipmentWeightRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "ShippedWeight"
      add field "ShippedVolume"
    }
    add layout "ShipmentInvNbr" {
      displayName = "ShipmentInvNbr"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "InventoryDocType"
      add field "InventoryRefNbr"
    }
    add field "NoteText" {
      textType = PlainMultiLine
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
  add container "Payments" {
    fieldsToShow = 4
    listActionsToExpand = 2
    formActionsToExpand = 2
    containerActionsToExpand = 1
    add layout "PaymentRefRow" {
      displayName = "PaymentRefRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "DocType" {
        listPriority = 70
      }
      add field "ReferenceNbr" {
        listPriority = 90
        pickerType = Searchable
      }
    }
    add layout "PaymentBalanceRow" {
      displayName = "PaymentBalanceRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "Balance"
      add field "Status" {
        listPriority = 60
      }
    }
    add layout "PaymentAppliedRow" {
      displayName = "PaymentAppliedRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "AppliedToOrder" {
        listPriority = 80
      }
      add field "TransferredToInvoice"
    }
    add layout "PaymentAmtRow" {
      displayName = "PaymentAmtRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "PaymentAmount"
      add field "Currency"
    }
    add group "PaymentDetailsGroup" {
      displayName = "Payment Details"
      collapsable = True
      collapsed = True
      add field "PaymentMethod" {
        selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
      }
      add field "CashAccount" {
        selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
      }
      add field "PaymentRef"
    }
    add field "NoteText" {
      textType = PlainMultiLine
    }
    add containerAction "CaptureCCPayment" {
      behavior = Void
      syncLongOperation = True
    }
    add containerAction "AuthorizeCCPayment" {
      behavior = Void
      syncLongOperation = True
    }
    add containerAction "VoidCCPayment" {
      behavior = Void
      syncLongOperation = True
    }
    add containerAction "MobileCreatePayment" {
      behavior = Void
      redirect = True
    }
    add containerAction "MobileCreatePrepayment" {
      behavior = Void
      redirect = True
    }
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      displayName = "Add Existing"
      behavior = Create
    }
    add selectionAction "Delete" {
      displayName = "Remove"
      behavior = Delete
    }
    add recordAction "ViewPayment" {
      displayName = "View Document"
      behavior = Void
      after = Close
      redirect = True
    }
    add recordAction "Delete" {
      displayName = "Remove"
      behavior = Delete
      after = Close
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
  add container "Relations" {
    fieldsToShow = 4
    listActionsToExpand = 1
    formActionsToExpand = 2
    containerActionsToExpand = 1
    add layout "RoleRow" {
      displayName = "RoleRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "Role" {
        listPriority = 110
        forceIsDisabled = True
      }
      add field "Type" {
        listPriority = 115
        forceIsDisabled = True
      }
    }
    add layout "PrimaryRow" {
      displayName = "PrimaryRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "Primary" {
        listPriority = 105
        listDisplayFormat = CaptionValue
        forceIsDisabled = True
      }
      add field "AddToCC" {
        listPriority = 100
        forceIsDisabled = True
      }
    }
    add field "DocumentDocument" {
      listPriority = 120
      forceIsDisabled = True
    }
    add field "Account" {
      pickerType = Searchable
      forceIsDisabled = True
    }
    add field "ContactContact" {
      pickerType = Searchable
      forceIsDisabled = True
    }
    add field "Email"
    add selectionAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
    }
    add recordAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
      after = Close
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
  add container "Approvals" {
    fieldsToShow = 5
    add field "Reason" {
      textType = PlainMultiLine
      listPriority = 10
      listDisplayFormat = CaptionValue
    }
    add layout "ApproverRow" {
      displayName = "ApproverRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "AssignedTo" {
        listPriority = 50
      }
      add field "Workgroup" {
        listPriority = 40
      }
    }
    add layout "ApprovalStatusRow" {
      displayName = "ApprovalStatusRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "Status" {
        listPriority = 30
      }
      add field "ApprovedBy" {
        displayName = "Approved By"
      }
    }
    add layout "ApprovalDatesRow" {
      displayName = "ApprovalDatesRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "AssignmentDate" {
        forceIsDisabled = True
      }
      add field "ApprovalDate" {
        listPriority = 20
      }
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
  add container "LineDetails" {
    visible = False
    fieldsToShow = 4
    listActionsToExpand = 2
    formActionsToExpand = 3
    containerActionsToExpand = 2
    add field "AllocWarehouse" {
      selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
    }
    add layout "AllocQtyRow" {
      displayName = "AllocQtyRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "Quantity"
      add field "Allocated" {
        listDisplayFormat = CaptionValue
      }
    }
    add field "LotSerialNbr"
    add layout "AllocInventoryRow" {
      displayName = "AllocInventoryRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "InventoryID" {
        forceIsVisible = True
        selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
      }
      add field "Subitem"
    }
    add layout "AllocShipOnRow" {
      displayName = "AllocShipOnRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "ShipOn"
      add field "Completed"
    }
    add layout "AllocShipQtyRow" {
      displayName = "AllocShipQtyRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "QtyOnShipments"
      add field "QtyReceived"
    }
    add field "UOM"
    add field "ExpirationDate"
    add field "MarkForPO"
    add field "RelatedDocument"
    attachments {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian,   we have to possibility :   add recordAction "Delete" {icon = "system://Trash"       behavior = Delete} for delete when we are on the record, and  add selectionAction "Delete" { icon = "system://Trash" behavior = Delete } when we are on the list.